# AngularJS: stale UI trying to load cachebusted HTML files that no longer exist when new version deployed

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, caching, single-page-application

I have an angularjs/ui-router application. All the html templates, which are lazyloaded by the framework, are cachebusted so that they are named `myTemplate.someHash.html`, and the references to those templates are also updated compile-time.

One problem that sometimes occurs is when I deploy a new version while a user is using the application. The sequence of events is as following:

1. The user has opened a page, which has a link on it to a state called *Summary*. The Summary state uses an HTML template called `summary.html`. But since we're cachebustering the HTML templates, this file is actually named `summary.12345.html` in version of the application currently loaded in the user´s browser.
2. A new release is deployed, which contained some changes to `summary.html`, causing it to get a new hash, so it's now called `summary.98765.html`.
3. The user clicks on the link, and angular tries to fetch `summary.12345.html` which nolonger exists, causing a 404.

Is there a good pattern for solving this?

My initial thought is to append some HTTP header in all requests, something like `Expected-Version: 999` (where 999 is the build number generated in CI), and if that is not the version running on the server, then the server will respond with something like "410 Gone", in which case the application will ask the user to refresh the browser.

But it would require some work on the server side, and I'm not sure how to inject this logic into the template loading on the client side either.

Also, since new versions are typically deployed a few times per week (sometimes many per day), and most of those releases don't even contain any changes that would break the SPA in the above way, I don't want to force the users to reload the page all the time.

Could one approach be to only show the "please refresh" message when a request results in a 404 **AND** the response contains a header that indicates that you're running a stale version of the SPA?

Or maybe there is a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in the following way.

I decided I don't want to ask users to refresh their browser every time a new release has been deployed, because many of those releases only contain backend changes.

I only want to ask them to refresh when a release has been deployed (since the time they opened the app in their browser) which contains changes to either:

- the javascript application (which is served as two bundles), or
- any of the html templates that angular lazyloads.

So I had to introduce the notion of a UI version. I decided that the definition of this UI version should be the SHA256 hash of all the filenames (just the names, since those already contain hashes for cachebusting) of the html templates mentioned above, concatenated with the names of the two js bundles (which are also cachebusted).

### Here's the solution.

#### Part 1

I added a step in my CI pipeline, after the js app has been compiled and cachebusted, but before the whole application is built into a Docker image. This new build step looks like this:

```js
const glob = require("glob");
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');

const jsPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
    glob("./js/*.js", {}, function (err, files) {
        if (!err) {
            resolve(files);
        }
    });
});

const htmlPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
    glob("./app/**/*.html", {}, function (err, files) {
        if (!err) {
            resolve(files);
        }
    });
});

Promise.all([jsPromise, htmlPromise]).then(([files1, files2]) => {
    const allFiles = files1.concat(files2);

    fs.writeFileSync(
        './ui-version.env',
        `UI_VERSION=${crypto.createHash('sha256').update(allFiles.sort().join()).digest('hex')}`
    );
});
```

As you can see, it writes it to a file called `ui-version.env`. I then refer to this file in the docker-compose.yml using the `env_file` command. This way, the backend application is now aware of the current UI version. And the backend now serves this data at the HTTP endpoint `GET /ui-version`.

#### Part 2

When the frontend app is loaded, it calls the above mentioned endpoint and stores the current UI version in memory.

When a new release has been deployed, a websocket message is sent to all connected frontend apps with a notification to check whether or not they are still running an up-to-date UI version. They do this by requesting the new endpoint mentioned above, and comparing the result to the version it saved on load.

**What about users who´s computers were in sleep mode or without internet connection when the websocket message was sent out?**

I already have event listeners setup in the SPA that goes off when the computer comes back from sleep mode, or when it recovers internet connection. So any of those events will now also trigger the UI version check.

To be honest, I'm not super excited about this solution. There are a lot of moving parts. It would be great if someone could offer a simpler solution. But unfortunately I'm skeptical that I will get any good answers at all.